# Retrieve friend's birthday information from Facebook Connect iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

When I logged in to Facebook Connect from an iOS application, is it possible to retrieve the "Birthday" of friends through Facebook Connect integrated with an iOS application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Graph api to get this info
check http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user